# Missing compiled element contents when unit testing ngView

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

After reading the angular ngViewSpec.js file, I've finally figured how to test my controller with routes, controllerAs and forms. Here is my unit test:

```
describe("mainControllerSpec", function() {

    var element;
    beforeEach(module("nisArch"));
    beforeEach(module("ngRoute"));

    it("clickSearch should change location with limitResults true", function () {
        var path, search;
        var ctrl;

        module(function () {
            return function ($rootScope, $compile) {
                element = $compile("<div ng-view></div>")($rootScope);
            };
        });

        module(function ($compileProvider, $routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when("/", {
                title: "Home",
                controller: getController,
                controllerAs: "vm",
                templateUrl: "templates/mainView.html"
            });
        });

        inject(function ($location, $controller, $rootScope, $route, $templateCache) {
            ctrl = $controller("mainController", { $location: $location });
            $location.path("/");
            $rootScope.$digest();
            //breakpoint here. element.html() == "". 
            //Expected contents of $templateCache.get(...)
            ctrl.queryString = "AS65402";
            ctrl.clickSearch();
            path = $location.path();
            search = $location.search();
            expect(path).toEqual("/Search");
            expect(search).toEqual({ q: "AS65402", limitResults: "true" });
        });

        function getController() {
            return ctrl;
        }

    });
});
```

If I understand correctly what's going on here: 
I create an element with my ng-view directive, compile it, bind it to the rootscope. I then create the route and controller. Finally I set the $location and do the main part of my unit test.

This is working fine and my test is passing. What's puzzling me is that I can't see the contents of element. I would have expected them to be the contents of templates/mainView.html after the router change and $digest(). But I get nothing. I injected $route to check $route.current.templateHtml and I injected $templateCache to check that. Both correct.

Should I not expect to find the contents using element.html()?
Or have I completely misunderstood what's going on here?
Thanks for any help or insight,
Marcus

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the magic is in element.siblings(). I got the first clue with element[0]:

```
<!-- ngView:  -->
```

Which explains why element.html() and element.text() were undefined

Everything I was looking for is under element.siblings()[0]:

```
<div class="ng-scope" ng-view="">...</div>
```

I found the element[0] trick from:
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/

Hope this helps someone,
Marcus

Comment: Thx a lot, this really guided me to the solution I needed

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to use `ngView[0].nextSibling` here is my test

```
  it 'check view content', ->
    inject ($route, $location, $rootScope, $httpBackend, $compile)->

      ngView = $compile("<div ng-view></div>")($rootScope)

      using $httpBackend, ->
        @.expectGET(url_Template).respond(html)
        @.expectGET(url_Data    ).respond test_Data


      $location.path(url)
      $httpBackend.flush()

      element = ngView[0].nextSibling
      $scope = angular.element(element).scope()
      $scope.team.assert_Is 'team-A'
      $scope.table.assert_Is metadata: 42
```